# How to fix "using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Recently faced with such a problem: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Reshape, Dropout, Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Activation, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
```

```py
IMAGE_SIZE = 128
IMAGE_CHANNELS = 3
IMAGE_DIR = 'dataset/'
```

```py
images_path = IMAGE_DIR 

training_data = []
```

```py
for filename in os.listdir(images_path):
    path = os.path.join(images_path, filename)
    image = Image.open(path).resize((IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    training_data.append(np.asarray(image))

training_data = np.reshape(training_data, (-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS))
training_data = training_data / 127.5 - 1
np.save('cubism_data.npy', training_data)
```

```py
PREVIEW_ROWS = 4
PREVIEW_COLS = 7
PREVIEW_MARGIN = 4
SAVE_FREQ = 100
NOISE_SIZE = 100
EPOCHS = 10000 
BATCH_SIZE = 32
GENERATE_RES = 3
IMAGE_SIZE = 128 
training_data = np.load('cubism_data.npy')
```

```py
def build_discriminator(image_shape):    
    model = Sequential()    
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, input_shape = image_shape, padding="same"))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))    
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0, 1), (0, 1))))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))    
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))    
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))    
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))    
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))    
    input_image = Input(shape=image_shape)
    validity = model(input_image)
    return Model(input_image, validity)
```

```py
def build_generator(noise_size, channels):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4 * 4 * 256, activation="relu", input_dim=noise_size))
    model.add(Reshape((4, 4, 256)))    
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))    
    model.add(UpSampling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))    
    for i in range(GENERATE_RES):
         model.add(UpSampling2D())
         model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
         model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
         model.add(Activation("relu"))    
    model.summary()
    model.add(Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=3, padding="same"))
    model.add(Activation("tanh"))    
    input = Input(shape=(noise_size,))
    generated_image = model(input)
    
    return Model(input, generated_image)
```

```py
def save_images(cnt, noise):
    image_array = np.full((
        PREVIEW_MARGIN + (PREVIEW_ROWS * (IMAGE_SIZE + PREVIEW_MARGIN)),
        PREVIEW_MARGIN + (PREVIEW_COLS * (IMAGE_SIZE + PREVIEW_MARGIN)), 3), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
    generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
    generated_images = 0.5 * generated_images + 0.5
    image_count = 0
    for row in range(PREVIEW_ROWS):
        for col in range(PREVIEW_COLS):
            r = row * (IMAGE_SIZE + PREVIEW_MARGIN) + PREVIEW_MARGIN
            c = col * (IMAGE_SIZE + PREVIEW_MARGIN) + PREVIEW_MARGIN
            image_array[r:r + IMAGE_SIZE, c:c + IMAGE_SIZE] = generated_images[image_count] * 255
            image_count += 1
    output_path = 'output'
    if not os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.makedirs(output_path)
            
    filename = os.path.join(output_path, f"trained-{cnt}.png")
    im = Image.fromarray(image_array)
    im.save(filename)
```

```py
image_shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS)
optimizer = Adam(1.5e-4, 0.5)
discriminator = build_discriminator(image_shape)
validity = discriminator(generated_image)
discriminator.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                      optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
generator = build_generator(NOISE_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS)
random_input = Input(shape=(NOISE_SIZE,))
generated_image = generator(random_input)
discriminator.trainable = Falsevalidity = discriminator(generated_image)
combined = Model([random_input, validity])
combined.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                 optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

And there this problem

```py
y_real = tf.ones((BATCH_SIZE, 1))
y_fake = tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, 1))
fixed_noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (PREVIEW_ROWS * PREVIEW_COLS, NOISE_SIZE))
cnt = 1

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    idx = np.random.randint(0, training_data.shape[0], BATCH_SIZE)
    x_real = training_data[idx]
 
    noise= np.random.normal(0, 1, (BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_SIZE))
    x_fake = generator.predict(noise)
 
    
    discriminator_metric_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(x_real, y_real)
    
discriminator_metric_generated = discriminator.train_on_batch(x_fake, y_fake)
 
discriminator_metric = 0.5 * np.add(discriminator_metric_real, discriminator_metric_generated)
generator_metric = combined.train_on_batch(noise, y_real)
    
if epoch % SAVE_FREQ == 0:
    save_images(cnt, fixed_noise)
    cnt += 1
    print(f"{epoch} epoch, Discriminator accuracy: {100*  discriminator_metric[1]}, Generator accuracy: {100 * generator_metric[1]}")
```

```
WARNING:tensorflow:8 out of the last 8 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x000001C884439D30> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-c0178347a645> in <module>
     12 
     13 
---> 14     discriminator_metric_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(x_real, y_real)
     15 
     16 discriminator_metric_generated = discriminator.train_on_batch(x_fake, y_fake)

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics, return_dict)
   1687     self._check_call_args('train_on_batch')
   1688     _disallow_inside_tf_function('train_on_batch')
-> 1689     with self.distribute_strategy.scope(), \
   1690          training_utils.RespectCompiledTrainableState(self):
   1691       iterator = data_adapter.single_batch_iterator(self.distribute_strategy, x,

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in __enter__(self)
   1230     for layer, trainable in self._compiled_trainable_state.items():
   1231       if (layer in self._current_trainable_state and
-> 1232           trainable != self._current_trainable_state[layer]):
   1233         self._should_set_trainable = True
   1234         break

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in __bool__(self)
    875       `TypeError`.
    876     """
--> 877     self._disallow_bool_casting()
    878 
    879   def __nonzero__(self):

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _disallow_bool_casting(self)
    488     else:
    489       # Default: V1-style Graph execution.
--> 490       self._disallow_in_graph_mode("using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
    491 
    492   def _disallow_iteration(self):

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _disallow_in_graph_mode(self, task)
    475 
    476   def _disallow_in_graph_mode(self, task):
--> 477     raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(
    478         "{} is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate"
    479         " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

If I add `@tf.function` before def build_discriminator (image_shape), then this error appears in the penultimate block of code(it does not disappear in the last):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    547     try:
--> 548       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    549     except TypeError:

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    547     try:
--> 548       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
    549     except TypeError:

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
     85   else:
---> 86     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
     87                     (bytes_or_text,))

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x000001C884818D30>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in convert(x)
    941         try:
--> 942           x = ops.convert_to_tensor_or_composite(x)
    943         except (ValueError, TypeError):

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor_or_composite(value, dtype, name)
   1620   """
-> 1621   return internal_convert_to_tensor_or_composite(
   1622       value=value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=False)

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor_or_composite(value, dtype, name, as_ref)
   1655   else:
-> 1656     return convert_to_tensor(
   1657         value,

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1498     if ret is None:
-> 1499       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1500 

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    337   _ = as_ref
--> 338   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    339 

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    262   """
--> 263   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    264                         allow_broadcast=True)

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    279   tensor_value.tensor.CopyFrom(
--> 280       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
    281           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape,

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    549     except TypeError:
--> 550       raise TypeError("Failed to convert object of type %s to Tensor. "
    551                       "Contents: %s. Consider casting elements to a "

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional'> to Tensor. Contents: <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x000001C884818D30>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-bf1d58de645b> in <module>
      1 image_shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS)
      2 optimizer = Adam(1.5e-4, 0.5)
----> 3 discriminator = build_discriminator(image_shape)
      4 validity = discriminator(generated_image)
      5 discriminator.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    694     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    697             *args, **kwds))
    698 

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3063     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3064     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3065         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3066             self._name,
   3067             self._python_function,

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
    989       # TensorArrays and `None`s.
--> 990       func_outputs = nest.map_structure(convert, func_outputs,
    991                                         expand_composites=True)
    992 

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    633 
    634   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 635       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    636       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    637 

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    633 
    634   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 635       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    636       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    637 

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in convert(x)
    942           x = ops.convert_to_tensor_or_composite(x)
    943         except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 944           raise TypeError(
    945               "To be compatible with tf.eager.defun, Python functions "
    946               "must return zero or more Tensors; in compilation of %s, found "

TypeError: To be compatible with tf.eager.defun, Python functions must return zero or more Tensors; in compilation of <function build_discriminator at 0x000001C884736AF0>, found return value of type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional'>, which is not a Tensor.
```

Comment: Replace the `if` with `tf.cond` as error message says `if` condition allowed only during Eager execution.